# Create model classes for Coredata database in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, core-data

I am creating a static library, and the database for the project is created programatically. It doesnot use any xcdatamodel file. I am using core data and I want to generate the model classes for the database. Someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The `.xcdatamodel` bundle generated by Xcode is an undocumented format, and I know of no way of generating this other than through Xcode's model layout tools.  I would not waste your time on reverse engineering this and just create the appropriate model you need in Xcode.

Your Core Data model structure should remain fairly static, so you should just need to do this once.  Your application or library can then create and add data to the model programmatically after this point.

When it comes to generation of code that corresponds with your Core Data model, you can have Xcode generate this for you by opening the model, selecting an entity, choosing the `File | New File...` menu option, and then selecting the Managed Object Class file type.  Pick the entities to create source files for you.

Additionally, you might want to look at 'Wolf' Rentzsch's [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) project for auto-generating these source files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Core Data is simply an SDK that uses SQLite3 in the background. So if you want to dynamically create tables then I would just use SQLite3 directly and not use Core Data.